# React - Show/Hide multiple divs from different check boxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react, I have certain domain in JS, I imagine this is a simple question but I have been searching for 2 hours and I haven't found a satisfactory answer :(

I have the check boxes:

```
<Col md="4">
  <FormGroup>
    <Label>Have Children</Label>
    <CustomInput type="radio" name="customRadio" label="Yes" value="yes" />
    <CustomInput type="radio" name="customRadio" label="No" value="no" />
  </FormGroup>
</Col>
<Col md="4">
  <FormGroup>
    <Label>Have Spouse</Label>
    ...(same as children input)
  </FormGroup>
</Col>
<Col md="4">
  <FormGroup>
    <Label>Have Family Members</Label>
    ...(same as children input)
  </FormGroup>
</Col>
```

If you click on "have children"
I want that some divs after, related to children, to be displayed. If not, they should be hidden. And the same for the other options.

I want to know what is the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: You could have a piece of state called e.g `isChildrenShown` that you set to `true` when clicking on the "Have Children" label, and use that state variable to conditionally render it. And then do the same for the 2 other form groups.

Comment: Here is the React documentation on Conditional Rendering - this is worth reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of the data structure beforehand.

From your question, I assume you simply want something like this:

1. If `children` checkbox is checked, show elements related to `children`
2. If `spouse` checkbox is checked, show elements related to `spouse`.
3. etc.

The way I see it, you need an array of checkboxes with each of their statuses (checked or not). You can store this information in the component state.

```
// in the constructor
this.state = {
  checkboxes: [
    { id: 1, label: 'children', checked: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'spouse', checked: false },
  ],
}
```

Then, in your `render()` function, you just need to loop through the array like this:

```
const { checkboxes } = this.state;

return (
  <div>
    {checkboxes.map((checkbox, index) => (
      <div>
        <label>{checkbox.label}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={checkbox.checked} onClick={() => this.toggleCheckBox(index)} />
        {checkbox.checked && <div>show this if the checkbox is checked</div>}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Just remember to implement `this.toggleCheckBox` method in the class. If you are unsure of how to do it, here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6wp99p6l9r?codemirror=1&fontsize=14) for you to check out.

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox should toggle a boolean in state.

You then conditionally render the children if the value in state is true.

So attach a checked value and change handler to your groups:

```
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>Have Children</Label>
        <CustomInput type="radio" name="customRadio" label="Yes" value="yes" onChange={() => this.handleChange} checked={this.state.visibility} />
        <CustomInput type="radio" name="customRadio" label="No" value="no" onChange={() => this.handleChange} checked={!this.state.visibility}/>
      </FormGroup>
```

The create the state value in your class and toggle it with the handleChange method

```
state = {visibility: false}

handleChange = () => this.setState({visibility: !this.state.visibility})
```

Then you can conditionally render your thing based on the visibility boolean, so...

```
<div>{this.state.visibility && <p>Now You see me</p>}</div>
```